# Spring MVC: How to assess the same model object for all/different jsp Pages?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have a function, which will return a `view.jsp` page with `var jsonString = '${jsonString}';`

```
private String jsonString = null; 
public ModelAndView importNetworkFromDB(
   this.jsonString = ajsonString;
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("view");
) 

@ModelAttribute("jsonString ")
public String getJsonString () {
    return jsonString ;
}
```

Is there any way to access `${jsonString}` variable in other jsp pages? (My json String is very big, cannot pass them using the session storage.)

Comment: No, but what you need isn't very clear to me. Normally you have a Model, a View and a Controller... You could define two different methods in the controller that retrieves the same model (the jsonString) and returns two different views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually have a process flow, which a view will be follow by another view by clicking "next" button. All these views share some commen objects. I used to store them in the session storage of the first view and fetch it in another page. But now the problem is size of the storage is not enough. I remember that in Struts2 , I can access the same object by <interceptor-ref name="scope"> </interceptor-ref>, Just wondering how could I do it in Spring MVC.